# Error in getting path of file on server

Tags: java, tomcat, path

I've a service class in `src.service.ABCservice`

In `ABCService class`, I need to write in a xml file.

The xml file is in resource folder, which is at same level of src folder

When i run it as a single java class though main method, I can write in the xml using path `./resource/aaa.xml` but when I run it on my tomcat server, it fails to read the file.

```
ERROR :  java.io.FileNotFoundException: .\resources\LocationOfOperation.xml (The system cannot find the path specified)
```

Please tell me how to reach the xml file and write in it.

Comment: If you are deploying a war, you can't write in that path, because the war is a zip file. I recommend you to write in another location, in a specific path in the operating system. Also, is this is strictly neccesary, check the exploded war format, and figure out the path out of the base path that you get with `new File(".").getAbsolutePath()`.

Answer (score 0):

When you run as single class, you can read project's file path, but when you package and deploy as web project you miss project path reference.

You must create a parameter (context param, file properties, ...) to point to a path that existing into web part, thus you can use the files contained in that path to your porpouses.